# Apple postion in snake game scala

Tags: scala, error-handling

I am trying in my snake game to find the number of free spots in the grid then call randomGen.randomInt(nrFreeSpots). Then place the apple at the position corresponding to the number I got. I get an error then when i call getcelltype(i,j) too many arguments, Although the p point is int x and int y, I don't know how to fix it?

```
def getCellType(p : Point): CellType = {
    for(i <- bodySize until 0 by -1){
      if(p == snakeTail(i)) return SnakeBody()
    }
    if(p == snakeTail(0)) return SnakeHead(headDirection)
    else if(p == applePosition) return Apple()
    Empty()
  }

  def defineApplePosition(): Point = {
    val freeCells = new Array[Point](gridDims.height * gridDims.width)
    var counter: Int = 0
    for(j <- 0 until gridDims.width; i <- 0 until gridDims.height){
      if(getCellType(i,j) == Empty()){
        freeCells(counter) = Point(i,j)
        counter += 1
      }
    }
    if(counter < 1) return null
    freeCells(random.randomInt(counter))
  }
```

Comment: What is the point of using **Scala** if you are going to program like this was **Python** or **Java**? - Anyways, `getCellType` receives one, and only one thing, a `Point`. It doesn't matter if a `Point` is structure of two fields, you can not pass just two arguments and expect the compiler to magically convert those to a `Point`; you have to create the Point yourself `getCellType(Point(x, y))`, but it may be worth rethinking if you really need that `Point` abstraction, if everywhere you use plain `Ints`.

Answer (score 2):

`getCellType` takes one argument, `p: Point`. You've attempted to call this function with two `Int`s. You need to create a `Point` out of the two `Int`s and call `getCellType` with it. It should then compile